# Splitting an array containing nested arrays using Scala in Azure Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently working on a project where I'm having to extract some horribly nested data out of a json document (output from Log Analytics REST API call), document structure example below (I have a lot more columns):

```
{
"tables": [
    {
        "name": "PrimaryResult",
        "columns": [
            {
                "name": "Category",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "count_",
                "type": "long"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            [
                "Administrative",
                20839
            ],
            [
                "Recommendation",
                122
            ],
            [
                "Alert",
                64
            ],
            [
                "ServiceHealth",
                11
            ]
        ]
    }
] }
```

I have managed to extract this json document into a data frame but I am stumped as to where to go from here.

The goal I am trying to achieve is an output like the below:

```
[{
"Category": "Administrative",
"count_": 20839
},
{
    "Category": "Recommendation",
    "count_": 122
},
{
    "Category": "Alert",
    "count_": 64
},
{
    "Category": "ServiceHealth",
    "count_": 11
}]
```

Ideally, I would like to use my columns array as the headers for each record. Then I want to split out each record array from the parent rows array in to its own record.

So far, I have tried flattening my raw imported data frame but this won't work as the rows data is an array of arrays.

How would I go about solving this conundrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit messy to deal with this, but here's a way to do it:

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline",true).json("filepath")

val result = df.select(explode($"tables").as("tables"))
    .select($"tables.columns".as("col"), explode($"tables.rows").as("row"))
    .selectExpr("inline(arrays_zip(col, row))")
    .groupBy()
    .pivot($"col.name")
    .agg(collect_list($"row"))
    .selectExpr("inline(arrays_zip(Category, count_))")

result.show
+--------------+------+
|      Category|count_|
+--------------+------+
|Administrative| 20839|
|Recommendation|   122|
|         Alert|    64|
| ServiceHealth|    11|
+--------------+------+
```

To get the JSON output, you can do

```
val result_json = result.agg(to_json(collect_list(struct("Category", "count_"))).as("json"))

result_json.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json                                                                                                                                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"Category":"Administrative","count_":"20839"},{"Category":"Recommendation","count_":"122"},{"Category":"Alert","count_":"64"},{"Category":"ServiceHealth","count_":"11"}]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Or you can save as JSON, e.g. with `result.save.json("output")`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `transform` function :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.read.option("multiline",true).json(inPath)

val df1 = df.withColumn("tables", explode($"tables"))
            .select($"tables.rows".as("rows"))
            .select(expr("inline(transform(rows, x -> struct(x[0] as Category, x[1] as _count)))"))

df1.show
//+--------------+------+
//|      Category|_count|
//+--------------+------+
//|Administrative| 20839|
//|Recommendation|   122|
//|         Alert|    64|
//| ServiceHealth|    11|
//+--------------+------+
```

Then saving into json file:

```
df1.save.json(outPath)
```